# KoaJs cant handle POST requests on CloudFunctions

Tags: node.js, express, google-cloud-functions, koa

I have a NodeJS Application written in [KoaJS](https://koajs.com/),

app.ts

```
const app = new Koa();

app.use(healthCheck());
app.use(bodyParser());
app.use(errorHandler());
app.use(endpoints);

export default app;
```

main.ts

```
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

if (!isCloudFunctions()) {
    app
        .listen(port, () => {
            console.info(`Listening at http://localhost:${port}`);
        })
        .on('error', console.error);
}

export const api = (req, res) => {
    app.callback()(req, res);
}
```

The app works well on `Cloud Runs`,
I can deploy the app on `Cloud Functions`, but on `Functions` the app can only handle `GET` requests.
If I try a POST request, I get this error

```
InternalServerError: stream is not readable
at getRawBody (/workspace/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:112:10)
at readStream (/workspace/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:178:17)
at AsyncFunction.module.exports [as json] (/workspace/node_modules/co-body/lib/json.js:39:21)
at executor (/workspace/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:113:5)
at parseBody (/workspace/node_modules/koa-bodyparser/index.js:100:26)
at new Promise (<anonymous>)
at bodyParser (/workspace/node_modules/koa-bodyparser/index.js:85:25)
at next (/workspace/node_modules/koa-compose/index.js:42:32)
at /workspace/webpack:/sample-explore/apps/sample-api/src/middlewares/health-check.ts:10:12
at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
```

I re-created the application in ExpressJS, and it works fine with both Runs and Functions

However I am really like the native `async/await` , `compose routing` of KoaJS

Does anyone know the reason why KoaJS can not handle POST requests on Cloud Functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The json body is automatically parsed in google cloud functions ([documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events#read_values_from_the_request)) and the `koa-bodyparser` middleware can't handle already parsed bodies.

More info on this issue: https://github.com/koajs/bodyparser/issues/127

Suggested fixes, from the issue thread, are to either use `ctx.req.body` instead of `ctx.request.body`, you'll need to parse it when running locally of course.
Alternatively add a middleware that will support already parsed bodies.

```js
function hybridBodyParser (opts) {
  const bp = bodyParser(opts)
  return async (ctx, next) => {
    ctx.request.body = ctx.request.body || ctx.req.body
    return bp(ctx, next)
  }
}

app.use(hybridBodyParser())
```

Comment: How to access files, how to read the buffer stream?